# exchange gather all hd wallet adresses fund

Tags: exchanges, bitcoin, cryptography, hd-wallets

every exchange has a HD wallet that stores the fund an assets of their clients but sometimes in order to keep peoples coins safe the exchanges have to move their assets to  more secure wallet like cold wallets, how do exchanges gather all the fund from HD wallet addresses (which is a lot of addresses) in order to send them to the cold wallet? what is this process called?

Comment: It doesn't have a particular name, they are just ETH or Token transfers.

Comment: thank you, but when do they do it? is there a limit for the amount of assets in hot wallet?

Comment: There's no fixed limit in general, it is according to the exchange volumen and security policies. Some exchanges have a "hot" wallet where funds are moved immediately when they are confirmed and a "cold" wallet where funds are moved more sporadically in the order of one transaction every couple of hours.